# Dynamically Pass Bind Variables to a SOQL Query With queryWithBinds Method

Tags: dynamic-soql, dynamic-binding, bind-variable, spring23

I was going through the new feature from Spring 23 release regarding Dynamically Pass Bind Variables to a SOQL Query With queryWithBinds Method. It seems like it is working when there is only one value in the map. I might be wrong and that is why I am asking this question here to understand it clearly. Below are some code snippet I wrote to try this out.

**Fetching all accounts and store it in map**

```
Map<String, Account> m = new Map<String, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account ]);
```

**Can I use m.keySet() with queryWithBinds to find out all contacts associated with these accounts?**

```
List<Contact> contacts = 
    Database.queryWithBinds('SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId in :m.keySet()',
                            m, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
```

**Also when I was trying to execute the below code and it is not working with the error that with :in I have to use some sort of iterable, but other than keySet() what I can use here.**

```
Map<String, Object> acctBinds = new Map<String, Object>();
acctBinds.put('acctName', 'GenePoint');
acctBinds.put('acctName', 'sForce');
acctBinds.put('acctName', 'Dickenson plc');
        
List<Account> accts = 
   Database.queryWithBinds('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name in :acctBinds.keySet()',
                            acctBinds, 
                            AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
        
System.Debug('accts: ' + accts.size());
```

Comment: In your example, you want map values rather than keys

Comment: Can I use map values here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic SOQL does not support dotted expressions as bind values. And the point of `queryWithBinds` is to be able to use the key name string from the map and obtain the object value whatever type that is.

So this is  likely to work for your case:

```
Map<String, Object> m = new Map<String, Object>();
m.put('names', new Set<String>{'GenePoint', 'sForce', 'Dickenson plc'}); 

... ['SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name in :names'], m, ...
```

And you can have multiple different key names as needed to bind values into expressions.